Both Chat:Chat() and TextChatService:DisplayBubble() not working, at all
I'm trying to produce a chat bubble over a part. It should be straight forward, but the now deprecated Chat:Chat() doesn't work, expectedly, but the alternative, TextChatService:DisplayBubble() failing as well.
local part = game.Workspace.Part

game:GetService("TextChatService"):DisplayBubble(part, "Hello world!")


Is this in a Script? Where is it located?

I've tried this exact code in literally everywhere in both local and server side scripts.
Currently it is a Script in ServerScriptStorage

Sorry, do you mean ServerStorage or ServerScriptService?

A surprising detail about TextChatService:DisplayBubble is that it only runs on client-sided scripts. This little detail was not under the DisplayBubble function documentation, but a small note in a guide about using Text Chat for NPCs.
So you need a LocalScript located in an appropriate container, or a Script whose RunContext is set to Client.
But I was able to get it working with something like this :
Set up your workspace like this :

Workspace
|-> Part
|->->ProximityPrompt (as a simple object to connect a listener to)
|->->Script  (set the RunContext property to 'Client')

Then in your Script :
local tcs = game:GetService("TextChatService")
local prox = script.Parent.ProximityPrompt
local part = script.Parent

prox.Triggered:Connect(function(playerWhoTriggered : Player)
    tcs:DisplayBubble(part, string.format("Hello %s", playerWhoTriggered.Name))
end)


This worked out. Hopefully with this information I can continue on to properly use this function.

A question, I've never seen a colon being used like that. What is it there for, and what does that accomplish?

Ah, playerWhoTriggered : Player is Luau (typed Lua). The colon next to a variable declaration let's the linter know what type / class the variable is.
